# A (Sort of) Generic Stack Implementation in C using Macros

Tags: algorithm, c, array, stack, macros

I spent some time implementing a generic stack in C using macros. Apart from general bugs and bad practices in my code, I was wondering about the viability of an implementation like this that uses macros. Note that the use of assert is only for this code; if I were coding an actual implementation that would be served to users, I would find a better solution.

## stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define stackdef(T, pfx)                                                       \
  typedef struct pfx##stack {                                                  \
    size_t capacity, N;                                                        \
    T *a;                                                                      \
  } pfx##stack;                                                                \
                                                                               \
  /* returns a pointer to a stack */                                           \
  pfx##stack *s##pfx##_create(void) {                                          \
    pfx##stack *st = malloc(sizeof *st);                                       \
                                                                               \
    assert(st);                                                                \
    st->capacity = 1;                                                          \
    st->N = 0;                                                                 \
    assert((st->a = malloc(sizeof *st->a)));                                   \
    return st;                                                                 \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* frees all memory that was allocated for the stack */                      \
  void s##pfx##_free(pfx##stack *st) {                                         \
    assert(st);                                                                \
    free(st->a);                                                               \
    free(st);                                                                  \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* returns true if the stack is empty */                                     \
  bool s##pfx##_isempty(const pfx##stack *st) {                                \
    assert(st);                                                                \
    return st->N == 0;                                                         \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* adds ITEM to the top of the stack */                                      \
  void s##pfx##_push(pfx##stack *st, T item) {                                 \
    assert(st);                                                                \
    if (st->N == st->capacity) {                                               \
      assert((st->a = realloc(st->a, (st->capacity *= 2) * sizeof st->a)));              \
    }                                                                          \
    st->a[st->N++] = item;                                                     \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* removes and returns the top element of the stack */                       \
  T s##pfx##_pop(pfx##stack *st) {                                             \
    assert(st);                                                                \
    assert(st->N > 0);                                                         \
    if (st->N == st->capacity / 4) {                                           \
      assert((st->a = realloc(st->a, (st->capacity /= 2) * sizeof st->a)));              \
    }                                                                          \
    return st->a[--(st->N)];                                                   \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* iterates through the stack and performs FN on each element */             \
  void s##pfx##_iterate(pfx##stack *st, void (*fn)(void *)) {                  \
    for (int i = st->N - 1; i >= 0; --i) {                                     \
      fn(&st->a[i]);                                                           \
    }                                                                          \
  }
#endif
```

## Example client

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

stackdef(char *, str);

int getword(char **s);

int main(void) {
  strstack *q = sstr_create();
  char *s;

  while (getword(&s)) {
    if (s[0] == '-' && s[1] == '\0') {
      printf("%s\n", (s = sstr_pop(q)));
      free(s);
    } else {
      sstr_push(q, s);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

// read the next word from stdin into S and return its length
int getword(char **s) {
  int c;
  int len = 0;

  assert((*s = malloc(sizeof **s)));
  **s = '\0';
  while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {}
  while (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    (*s)[len++] = c;
    assert((*s = realloc(*s, (len + 1) * sizeof **s)));
    (*s)[len] = '\0';
    c = getchar();
  }
  ungetc(c, stdin);
  return len;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overall, your code looks good.

**On naming**

I would rename `stackdef` to `DEFINE_STACK_TYPE` since, in C, macros are UPPER_CASE.

```
typedef struct pfx##stack {                                                  
    size_t capacity, N;                                                        
    T *a;                                                                      
} pfx##stack;
```

I would rather do:

```
typedef struct pfx##_stack {                                                 
    size_t capacity;                                                           
    size_t size;                                                               
    T* storage_array;                                                          
} pfx##_stack;
```

Note that I added `_` in `pfx##_stack` in order to separate the type name and the `stack`.

```
void s##pfx##_free(pfx##stack *st)
```

I would write rather:

```
void stack_##pfx##_free(...)
```

That way, you are more verbose about the fact that the data structure is a stack.

**Miscellaneous**

```
if (st->N == st->capacity / 4) {                                           
    assert((st->a = realloc(st->a, (st->capacity /= 2) * sizeof st->a)));              
}
```

Very good. That way, you keep the push/pop operations amortized constant time. However, you should not realloc if `st->capacity == 1`. Actually, I would define, for example, 8 as the `MINIMUM_CAPACITY` and rely on it.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this rewrite in mind:

**`stack.h`**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 8;

#define DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(T, pfx)                                              \
      typedef struct pfx##_stack {                                             \
        size_t capacity;                                                       \
        size_t size;                                                           \
        T* storage_array;                                                      \
      } pfx##_stack;                                                           \
                                                                               \
  /* returns a pointer to a stack */                                           \
  pfx##_stack* stack_##pfx##_create(void) {                                    \
    pfx##_stack* stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);                                \
                                                                               \
    assert(stack);                                                             \
    stack->capacity = MINIMUM_CAPACITY;                                        \
    stack->size = 0;                                                           \
    assert((stack->storage_array =                                             \
        malloc(sizeof(*stack->storage_array) * stack->capacity)));             \
    return stack;                                                              \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* frees all memory that was allocated for the stack */                      \
  void stack_##pfx##_free(pfx##_stack* stack) {                                \
    assert(stack);                                                             \
    free(stack->storage_array);                                                \
    free(stack);                                                               \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* returns true if the stack is empty */                                     \
  bool stack_##pfx##_isempty(const pfx##_stack* stack) {                       \
    assert(stack);                                                             \
    return stack->size == 0;                                                   \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* adds ITEM to the top of the stack */                                      \
  void stack_##pfx##_push(pfx##_stack* stack, T item) {                        \
    assert(stack);                                                             \
    if (stack->size == stack->capacity) {                                      \
      assert((stack->storage_array =                                           \
        realloc(stack->storage_array,                                          \
               (stack->capacity *= 2) * sizeof stack->storage_array)));        \
    }                                                                          \
    stack->storage_array[stack->size++] = item;                                \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* removes and returns the top element of the stack */                       \
  T stack_##pfx##_pop(pfx##_stack* stack) {                                    \
    assert(stack);                                                             \
    assert(stack->size > 0);                                                   \
    if (stack->size == stack->capacity / 4                                     \
        && stack->size > MINIMUM_CAPACITY) {                                   \
      /* Very good!:) */                                                       \
      assert((stack->storage_array,                                            \
        realloc(stack->storage_array,                                          \
               (stack->capacity /= 2) * sizeof stack->storage_array)));        \
    }                                                                          \
    return stack->storage_array[--(stack->size)];                              \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  /* iterates through the stack and performs FN on each element */             \
  void stack_##pfx##_iterate(pfx##_stack* stack, void (*fn)(void *)) {         \
    for (size_t i = stack->size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {                            \
      fn(&stack->storage_array[i]);                                            \
    }                                                                          \
  }
#endif
```

**`main.c`**

````
#include "stack.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

DEFINE_STACK_TYPE(char*, string)

int getword(char** s);

int main(void) {
    string_stack* q = stack_string_create();
    char* s;

    while (getword(&s)) {
        if (s[0] == '-' && s[1] == '\0') {
            printf("%s\n", (s = stack_string_pop(q)));
            free(s);
        }
        else {
            stack_string_push(q, s);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// read the next word from stdin into S and return its length
int getword(char** s) {
    int c;
    int len = 0;

    assert((*s = malloc(sizeof * *s)));
    **s = '\0';
    while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {}
    while (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        (*s)[len++] = c;
        assert((*s = realloc(*s, (len + 1) * sizeof * *s)));
        (*s)[len] = '\0';
        c = getchar();
    }
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    return len;
}
```
````